# Robo3T bulkWrite fails without error object

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm trying to do a bulk write operation on the mongo db shell. I'm trying to combine two properties on every document into one new property (sender.street + sender.houseNumber = sender.addressLine1)

Since even on our staging server there are over 7000 documents to update it takes forever so I figured using bulk operations to be a good idea. Here's my script so far:

```
// select street + housenumber into new temporary collection
var senderLine1 = db.getCollection('mailItem').aggregate([
    { $project: { addressLine1: { $concat: [ "$sender.street", " ", "$sender.houseNumber"] } } }
]);

var bulkOps = [];
// collect all operations into array
senderLine1.forEach(
    function(line1) {
        bulkOps.push({ 
            updateOne: { 
                  "filter" : { "_id" : line1._id },
                  "update" : { $set : { "sender.addressLine1" : line1.addressLine1 } }
                } 
        });
    }
);
try {
    db.mailItem.bulkWrite(bulkOps, { ordered : false });
} catch (e) {
    print(e);
}
```

Now I'm expecting to see a `BulkWriteError` object but all I get is `Error: error doing query: failed` in my Robo3T result view.

The selection seems to be going well, I can see the results. Also I can print the array and the generated operations are looking good. Example:

```
{
    "updateOne" : {
        "filter" : {
            "_id" : "bc3f65bd-5c32-4577-a57a-1c7665e1984b"
        },
        "update" : {
            "$set" : {
                "sender.addressLine1" : "someStreet 123"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I execute just the one it's working fine:

```
db.mailItem.bulkWrite(
[
    { "updateOne" : 
        {
            "filter" : {"_id" : "bc3f65bd-5c32-4577-a57a-1c7665e1984b" },
            "update" : { "$set" : { "sender.addressLine1" : "someStreet 123" } }
        }
    }
])
```

Just the bulk is not executing. I'm really at a loss why that is since I'm not getting any errors.

**EDIT**

For a reduced number of documents (like 100) this runs just fine. It starts to fail around 500 so it looks like the root issue revolves around a timeout or other limited resources.

However getting an ErrorOjbect that I can work with instead of `Error: error doing query: failed` would also be nice. Is this an issue with Robo3T maybe?

Comment: `Error: error doing query: failed` yes this is an issue of Robo3T. I would not advise continued use of this. The biggest problem is that the release is really tied to the MongoDB 3.4 build of the shell, and this will certainly cause ongoing problems since development on this seems to have stalled. Actually after a recent dicussion, pending coming up with an alternate JavaScript "runner" environment, you are probably better off just doing a simple listing with nodejs for this sort of operation. Also I would not be attempting to store a whole array of 7000 in memory.

Comment: You should be able to increase the timeout for Robo3T, but simply running this in the shell would be far better. Simply cut and paste from your favorite editor. So you really also should be sending in "batches" of 1000 items of so through the `bulkWrite()`. The underlying driver will do this anyway, but altering your script to write once every 1000 items and clear the array is going to stop memory being chewed up.

Comment: Thank's so much for your input. I've switched to NoSQLBooster and the script is running for all 7000 entries. I'm not too worried about keeping the agregation in memory, it's just a rather small json with around 30.000 mostly empty lines. Sending batches to the bulkWrite sounds like a good idea although I again think, 1000 sounds too small. After all, mongo itself splits bulks into chunks of 100,000. For larger bulks I'll also go directly to the mongo shell instead of using a GUI wrapper, that's for sure. So thank's again.

Comment: `100,000` where are you reading that? Pretty sure it's `1000` the last time I was digging around driver internals. It's always 16MB at any rate. Funny how I was only just downloading NoSQLBooster myself. Part of an end result discussion about Robo3T being quite broken and the lack of Modern ECMAScript support in the current shell since it's based around a years old JS Engine.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/  says "The number of operations in each group cannot exceed the value of the maxWriteBatchSize of the database. As of MongoDB 3.6, this value is 100,000. This value is shown in the isMaster.maxWriteBatchSize field."

Comment: Okay. It changed in 3.6. Previously it was 1000. This is confirmed on [older release versions of the same page.](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#execution-of-operations)